# Drag Function References from one block to another

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I'd like to know if there is a way to drag the cells that map to a function from one group of cells to another? It's a bit easier to explain with an example, so:

[image]

In this example I want to be able to drag the function references in cells G41 to H43 to the corresponding cells in the block J41 to K43 so they apply in the same orientation in cell B51 at the bottom of the image. Does anyone know if this is possible?